# PyOpenGL: glUniform1f gives TypeError

Tags: python, shader, ctypes, pyopengl

My problem is that when I want to call glUniform1f() it gives this error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

I just cant figure out what possibly might cause this.

My Code:

```
# initialization
glutInit()  # initialize glut
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE)
glutInitWindowSize(width, height)  # set window size
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)  # set window position
window = glutCreateWindow(b"window")  # create window with title


def make_shader(type, shader_src):
    shader = glCreateShader(type)
    glShaderSource(shader, shader_src)
    glCompileShader(shader)
    shader_ok = None
    #show_info_log(shader,glGetShaderiv, glGetShaderInfoLog)
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, shader_ok)
    if(not shader_ok):                                  ####shader_ok is still None
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)
        print("failed to compile shader")
    return shader



program = make_program(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)
texture = 0.33
uniform_texture = glGetUniformLocation(program, b"alpha[0]")

glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
glUseProgram(program)

glUniform1f(uniform_texture, texture)      ####Fails with TypeError: Wrong type
```

I also cant get any Log from this:

```
glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)
```

or this

```
log = ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.c_char, 100)
leng = ctypes.c_int(1)
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, leng)
glGetProgramInfoLog(program, leng, leng, log)
```

Code samples with shaders, that do not use glUniform1f() work though

Comment: When calling a function, you need to set its `argtypes` and `restype`, otherwise they will default to `int`.

Comment: What happens if you do something like `glUniform1fv(uniform_texture, 1, numpy.array(texture, dtype="float"))`

Answer (score 0):

CristiFati was right, I had to specify argtypes of the glUniform1f method.